# How do I output a hidden password field as part of Drupal form?

Tags: forms

I want to alter an existing Drupal form built with form API to contain a hidden *password* field.  (I.e. I want to create a honeypot field in the form that only 'bots will see and fill in, while humans will leave this field it empty).

The HTML I want included in the form shall be something like this:

```
<input type="password" name="password" style="display:none;" />
```

I've looked  at `hook_FORM_ID_alter`, but so far I haven't seen how it can help me with this.

I think I am looking for a way to theme this particular field, some way to manipulate the HTML *after* it has been rendered, but before it shown to the human (or 'bot), but I am open for other answers as well.

(For what it is worth: I am using Drupal 7.)

Comment: Have you looked at the Honeypot module itself?  Eg, https://drupal.org/project/honeypot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want [Honeypot](http://drupal.org/project/honeypot) module as mentioned by [Jimajamma](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/4255/jimajamma), you can do it with Form API [`#attributes`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) all right:

```
$form['pass'] = array(
  '#type' => 'password',
  '#title' => t('Password'),
  '#maxlength' => 64,
  '#size' => 15,
  '#attributes' = array('style' => array('display:none;'));
);
```

Of course it's easy to catch `display:none` in bot's code. It's also common and not so much harder to find out that class applied is styled with it in CSS. There are two methods that are not yet so easy to catch:

- Using box model and overflow to make element hidden under other HTML boxes.
- JavaScript code to move it out of sight or apply `display: none` to it

In both cases you shouldn't use obvious identifiers in html, like `.honeypot` or `.hidden`, as this will be probably easily found by the bot, too. Also, `z-index` usually isn't the way to go, as it tells bot "this element is under other one", or "this element is over other one, hides something".

Comment: It's better to hide the field with CSS/JS (i.e. outside of the markup) for a honeypot. It's trivial for a bot to detect `style="display:none;"` in HTML. Hell you could even use a regex for it, it's that simple! (not disputing your answer, which is exactly what the OP asked for, just saying)

Comment: @Clive I just posted code that generates exactly what OP asked for. I assumed he sees it as an example and otherwise knows what he's doing. I'll elaborate a bit more.